# Accessing the public response version of a Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Does the Apps Script Form Service only allow access to forms that the user has been given edit access to? I'm trying to read the question data for end users who only have access to the public (response) version of the form.

It works as expected for forms that I have edit access to but for others I get this error message on openById():

`Exception: No item with the given ID could be found. Possibly because you have not edited this item or you do not have permission to access it.`

Comment: Short answer: Yes

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You need edit access to access the form.

[Relevant documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#openById(String)):

> Throws an exception if the ID is invalid or the user does not have permission to open the form.

[Google docs like  Google sheets can be published](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965). Google forms is published by default. No one with the published link of any type of Google document like Google sheets can access the actual file through `openById()`. It's a similar case here.

Comment: But the user does have permission to open the form, they just can't edit it. If this were a regular Google Doc it would make sense but one of the points of Forms is that users can interact with them without being shared the file in their Drive.

Comment: @RobFlaherty [Google docs like  Google sheets can be published](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965). Google forms is published by default. No one with the published link of Google sheets can access the actual file through `openById()`. It's a similar case here.

Comment: Thanks. What's confusing to me is why the Forms API supports [submitting responses programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response) if only people with edit access can interact with the form since form respondents are typically not collaborators.

Comment: @RobFlaherty You might have other non-google forms, from which you get responses and you might want to collect in them in one place. In fact, it makes no sense for end users to have programmatic submission capabilities. End users are typically expected to submit the form through the  user interface.

Answer (score 1):

We need access.

**Why ?**

There is a difference between open form by going to https://xyz url. And accessing it via script (i.e. FormApp.openById(formId))

Both are different things.

When we go to form url, we are actually not accessing the form object it self. We're just accessing the web interface of same.
Whereas, Form.openById(formId) fetches the form object itself.